# C++ using template to specialize a class template

Tags: c++

I am interested in the following code and would like to know what the name of this grammar is.

```
//Define a class template
template <class T>
class my_unique_ptr{}

//What is this?
template <class T>
class my_unique_ptr<T[]>{}
```

The full example can be found here https://medium.com/swlh/c-smart-pointers-and-how-to-write-your-own-c0adcbdce04f

I know the execution result of this code, but I do not know what the grammar is. I've tried to search but did not find any results. It looks like an explicit specialization but does not have the common header `template<>`. The grammar also looks like a function overloading but it applies to a class. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: they are called class templates, not template classes (they are no classes)

Comment: Thanks, @Human-Compiler. that is a typo. I feel that template partial specialization may be the right direction. I will check this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a `template` [*partial specialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```cpp
template <class T>
class my_unique_ptr{};

template <class T>
class my_unique_ptr<T[]>{}; // <-- Partial specialized when 'T' matches 'T[]'
```

A partial specialization of a class template is, itself, still a class template that will only be instantiated when a type matches the specialization. In the case of `T[]`, this matches when the full type ends in `[]`. For example, `my_unique_ptr<int[]>` would instantiate the partial specialization with `T` = `int`.

This is different from a full template specialization, which is in terms of a discrete, fixed type and is not, itself, considered a template. For example:

```cpp
template <>
class my_unique_ptr<int>{}; // <-- full specialization in terms of 'int'
```

Comment: Thanks, That is exactly what I am looking for. I appreciate the info!